# Global variable and innerHTML

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

I'm trying to get a random name from my array to display once the button is clicked. In the console I get "Uncaught ReferenceError: arry is not defined" which I assume is because arry is not a global variable. How can I remedy this situation?

[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/umiVUgoP/3/edit?html,js,console,output)

```
var randomName = function() {
  arry = ["Kevin", "John", "Mabel", "Lucy", "Isabella", "Ryan", "Clyde"];
    var random = arry[Math.round(Math.random() * arry.length)];
    return random;
};

// create button
var button = document.createElement("input");
var id = "btn";
  button.type = "submit";
  button.value = "click me!";
  button.setAttribute("id", "btn");

document.body.appendChild(button);

// initialize function
window.onload = function() {
// add event listener
  document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = arry[0].random;
     console.log("hi");
    }   
  );
};
```

Comment: Since you seem to have your problem solved now,  you should select one of the answers as the best answer by clicking the checkmark to the left of the preferred answer in order to finish the proper procedure for asking a question here on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line:

```
document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = arry[0].random;
```

to this:

```
document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = randomName();
```

Working demo: http://jsbin.com/xugeg/1

You created the function `randomName()` to fetch a random value from your array and all you need to do is to call it.

`arry[0].random;` is wrong because `arry[0]` is a string and does not have a property named `random`.

Comment: This is the correct answer. To add to this, though, the OP should put "var" before the definition of "arry", so that the function isn't assigning "arry" into the global "window" object.

Comment: @MichaelAaronSafyan - that depends upon whether the OP wants `arry` to be global or not.  I wasn't sure what the OP's intention was, but good point that it is global and probably doesn't need to be.

Comment: Forgive me, I'm very new to JS.

Comment: @CrystalH - I don't understand what you mean "prints the whole randomName function"?  Perhaps you don't have the `()` in `randomName()` as in my answer. It executes the randomName function and assigns the return value from that function to the innerHTML.  The return value from that function is a random value from your array.  It works here: http://jsbin.com/xugeg/1/

Comment: I understand that's what it should be, but for some reason I'm getting this in my index.html file. http://snag.gy/jtY51.jpg

Comment: @CrystalH - look at my version of your jsbin.  I think you're missing the parens on `randomName()` in `document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = randomName();`.

Comment: Oh man, what an embarrassing mistake! It must be past my bedtime lol. Thanks again!

Comment: @jfriend00, it's hard to imagine that it is intentional (and it is a pretty bad code smell to create global variables like that).

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use your existing `randomName()` function?

Simply replace this line

```
document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = arry[0].random;
```

with

```
document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = randomName();
```